# mobile css for radio button not applying in knock template binding

Tags: jquery-mobile, knockout-mapping-plugin

I have tried to use `knockoutjs` template binding to bind fieldsets dynamically which contain group of radio buttons. Here my problem is mobile radio button css not applying for radio buttons. I have searched in stackoverflow I have found issue for button but i didn't find for radio buttons. So can you please find me the solution

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="MobileQuestionTemplate"> 
     <div data-role="fieldcontain"> 
        <div class="divborder">  
            <label id="l2" for="select-choice-1" class="questiontext"  data-bind="text:                          QuestionText"></label> 
            <br />    
            <fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-mini="true"  align="center" data-       bind="attr: { visible: QuestionType==13,id:QuestionID+'_fld'},template: {name:'MobileOptionTemplate', foreach: OptionList}"></fieldset>  
        </div>  
    </div>
</script>
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="MobileOptionTemplate"> 
    <input type="radio" data-bind="attr: {id:QuestionID+'_'+OptionID+'_rbt',val:OptionID,name: QuestionID+'_selectedObjects'}"/>
    <label data-bind="text: OptionText ,attr: { for: QuestionID+'_'+OptionID+'_rbt'}" /> 
</script>
<table id="tblMobileMgrQuestions" data-bind="template: {name:'MobileQuestionTemplate', foreach: MobileManagerviewmodel.ManagerQuestions}">
</table>
```

Can you please tell me where I need to change the code in `js` to apply `css`

```
$.ajax(
{
    url: "/Render/LoadSurveyManagerQuestions?surveyGuid=" + surveyGuid + "&surveyItemGuid=" + rsg,
    success: function (result) 
    {
        ko.bindingHandlers['button'] = 
        {
            init: function (element, valueAccessor) 
            {
                debugger;
                $(element).button(ko.utils.unwrapObservable(valueAccessor()));
            }
        }
        debugger;
        var SurveyManagerQuestion = function (managerQuestions) 
        {
            var Self = this;
            Self.ManagerQuestions = ko.observableArray(managerQuestions);

            Self.AssignQuestionAnswer = function (option) 
            {
                ko.utils.arrayFirst(Self.ManagerQuestions(), function (question) 
                {
                    if (question.QuestionID == option.QuestionID) 
                    {
                        question.OptionId = option.OptionID;
                        question.OptionText = option.OptionText;
                    }
                });
            };

            Self.Save = function () 
            {
                alert('hi');
            };
        };
        debugger;
        MobileManagerviewmodel = new SurveyManagerQuestion(result);
        ko.applyBindings(MobileManagerviewmodel, document.getElementById("tblMobileMgrQuestions"));
    }
});
```

Thanks for any help in advance.

Comment: use `$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio('refresh')` after appending them dynamically.

Comment: when i use above refresh methos iam getting this error "Uncaught cannot call methods on checkboxradio prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Comment: Ok, then try this `$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio().trigger('create')`.

Comment: field set data-type="horizantal" also not working for me

Comment: Add this `/
$( '.selector' ).controlgroup().trigger('create');`

Comment: when i select radio button only radio button color chandging to blue color not whole label.. i need the total label color change to blue

Comment: You mean the text inside the button?

Comment: not actually whole button

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28257/discussion-between-omar-and-user1622436)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To enhance the markup of radio buttons dynamically, use the below.

```
$('input[type=radio]').checkboxradio().trigger('create')
```

Comment: @user1622436 do you have them wrapped by a fieldset? `<fieldset data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" >`

Comment: yes , i have written like this <fieldset data-type="horizantal"   data-role="controlgroup"  data-bind="attr: { visible: QuestionType==13,id:QuestionID+'_fld'},template: {name:'MobileOptionTemplate', foreach: OptionList}">
                </fieldset>